# RabbitMQ transfer rates speed up?

Tags: c#, erlang, rabbitmq, producer-consumer

I look for ideas how to speed up message transfers through RabbitMQ.

I installed the latest version on Windows 64 bit, running a server on my local machine on which I also publish and consume to/from through a C# implementation. I initially maxed out at 40,000 messages per second which is impressive but does not suit my needs (I compete with a custom binary reader which can handle 24 million unparsed 16 byte large byte arrays per second; obviously I dont expect to get close to that but I attempt to improve at least). I need to send around 115,000,000 messages as fast as possible. I do not want to persist the data and the connection is gonna be direct to one single consumer. I then built chunks of my 16b byte arrays and published onto the bus without any improvement. The transfer rate maxed out at 45mb/second. I find this very very slow given the fact that in the end it should just boil down to raw transmission speed because I could create byte arrays the size of several megabytes where the efficiency rate of routing by the exchange becomes negligible vs raw transmission speed. Why does my message bus max out at 45mb/second transfer speed?

Comment: if there's only 1 consumer, why not send direct over TCP? you don;t really need a message bus.

Comment: What's your IO (network, disk) and CPU look like during these tests?

Comment: probably you should look at zeromq instead of rabbitmq. Your task seems to be suitable for 0mq. At least they claim about 3_000_000 messages per second on that message size (16 bytes). http://www.zeromq.org/results:0mq-tests-v03

Comment: @Vladimir, what queuing system do you suggest? I use C# and target .Net 4.0.

Comment: Xepoch, hardly any usage of resources. I have the fastest SSD money can currently buy and manage with my own custom binary reader, including parsing a transfer speed on random access reads of 200mb/second from physical storage into memory and subsequent parsing of the byte array to C# object. For sure I am not constrained by system resources.

Comment: Odobenus, thanks I am actually considering it at the moment. But can I enforce same order delivery of messages as the published message order? Also can I make connectors function as consumers and producers at the same time, consuming and producing different message types. My highest priority is speed and message order. No persistence needed, no fancy broker needed.

Comment: If you are using TCP then you just queue the messages in memory as they arrive and then have your consumer pull them off the queue and process them. You probably want a blocking queue of some sort (sorry, don't write much C#). TCP of course guarantees delivery in order.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks, I played with blocking collections and it works. I would have to implement every single thing myself through. I found ZeroMQ and play with it right now because it is very lightweight but a lot faster than RabbitMQ (for obvious reasons as 0MQ is brokerless). It could be its exactly what I need. I still test to see what latency numbers and throughput looks like, if it does not satisfy my need then I will logically have to end up with my own blocking collection and need to implement whatever other functionality I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bump...and Update: Have not seen any answer to this question in a longer time. I am a bit surprised not a single RabbitMQ developer chimed in. I played extensively with RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ. I decided that RabbitMQ is not up to the task when looking at high throughput in-process messaging solutions. The broker implementation and especially parsing logic is a major bottleneck to improving throughput. I dropped RabbitMQ from my list of possible options.

There was a white paper out describing how they provided a solution to managing low latency, high throughput options financial data streams but it sounds to me all they did was throwing hardware at it rather than providing a solution that targets low latency, high throughput requirements.

ZeroMQ, did a superb job after I studied the documentation more intensively. I can run communication in-process, it provides stable enough push/pull, pub/sub, req/rep, and pair/pair patterns which I need. I was looking for blocking logic within the pub/sub pattern which ZeroMQ does not provide (it drops messages instead when a high watermark is exceeded), but the push/pull pattern provides blocking. So, pretty much all I needed is provided for. The only gripe I have is with their understanding of event processing; the event structure implementation through poll/multiplex is not very satisfactory.